# Unexpected keyword argument 'padding'

Tags: typeerror, large-language-model, inference, llama

I've fine-tuned Llama2 on my dataset according to the tutorial described [here at datacamp](https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/fine-tuning-llama-2). However, when I get to the generation, an error occurs on the following block of code:

```
# Run text generation pipeline with our next model
pipe = pipeline(task="text-generation", model=model, tokenizer=model, max_length=150)
prompt = "I need to book tickets from Paris to London"
result = pipe(f"<s>[INST] {prompt} [/INST]")
print(result[0]['generated_text'])
```

Getting error

```
TypeError: LlamaForCausalLM.forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'padding'
```

I don't understand, what have gone wrong as `.forward()` method is not an explicit one. I'm not quite sure, where's this 'padding' argument came from. Any suggestions on solving this one?